# Timed slide of the element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to have an element slide left 10 seconds after the page loads. But i do not want it to disappear from the page entirely. I just want it to slide 200px. Then when I click remaining visible part i want it to slide back to the right.

not really sure how to set the distance... Here's what i have so far:

```
$("#myEl").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({width:'toggle'},500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/edemer/2/edit)*

```
function tabHide(){                             // define a 'HIDE' function
  $('#tab').stop().animate({left:-150},1000); 
}

function tabShow(){                             // define a 'SHOW' function
  $('#tab').stop().animate({left: -1 },1000);
}

// Now let's play with this functions:

setTimeout(function(){                          // run 'HIDE' after 10"
  tabHide();
},10000);

$('#tab').toggle(function(){                    // click toggle 'SHOW' / 'HIDE'
   tabShow();
},function(){
   tabHide();
});
```

[jQuery .toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
[jQuery .stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#myEl").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('left')) {
        $(this).animate({ left: '+=200' }, 500).removeClass('left');
    } else {
        $(this).animate({left:'-=200'}, 500).addClass('left');
    }
});
```

I've made a [JSFiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/9M3fk/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$(function () {
   var $myEl = $('#myEl');
   var orgPos = $myEl.position().left;

   $myEl.click(function(){
      //Moves to origPos after click
      $(this).stop(true, false).animate({left: orgPos},500); 
   })
   .animate({left: '-=200'}, 10000); //Animates for 10 secs
});
```

Edit: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XuGpD/2/) <-- Updated with bigger div